# ubuntu 12.04 cant install dual boot on raid0, installer cant detect windows7

Tags: windows, dual-boot, raid

I just downloaded the .iso and launched it on a live USB. Im actually writing this from the live session. I want to install ubuntu 12.04 along with my windows 7. I have my system set up with 2x1TB RAID0. When Im trying to install the only options I have are to erase the whole disk to make a clean install or to go into the advanced partion thing... It says it cant detect any other OS though I have a legit version of Windows 7 installed! Please I have searched so much and cant anything... I really want this to work... What can be wrong? Thanks in advance...

I also tried

`sudo dmraid -tay`

But it said it couldnt detect any raid disk. But I know it should work cause my windows 7 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is going to ubuntu.com to download the file WUBI.EXE. Or you can use this link to download the file

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer